# Changing listview row background color while swiping

Tags: android, listview, swipe, swipe-gesture, motionevent

I need to implement such a feature. User swipes left the item of the listview and another Activity is opens. When user starts swiping left, the background color of the listview item should be green and when he finish swiping, the new Activity should opens and background color of the item should become white.

I have SwipeDetector class which detects my swiping events:

```
public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to Top
        Start,
        Stop,
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private static final float HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 5;
    private static final float VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY ,  stopX, stopY;
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

    public boolean swipeDetected() {
        return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return mSwipeDetected;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            mSwipeDetected = Action.Start;
            return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // horizontal swipe detection
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX <= 0) {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Left to Right");
                            mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaX > 0) { 
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                            mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else 

                    // vertical swipe detection
                    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE) 
                    {
                        // top or down
                        if (deltaY < 0) {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Top to Bottom");
                            mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (deltaY > 0) 
                        {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe Bottom to Top");
                            mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                            return false;
                        }
                    } 
                    Log.i("delta X", Float.toString(deltaX));
                    return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {

             stopX = event.getX();
             stopY = event.getY();
             float stopValue = upX-stopX;

             Log.i("StopX value",Float.toString(stopValue));
                 Log.i("StopX value",Float.toString(stopX));
                 Log.i("DownX value",Float.toString(downX));
                 Log.i("UpX value",Float.toString(upX));
               //
                 mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
             return false;
        }


        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and how I use it in my Activity:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
          {
                  if (swipeDetector.getAction()== swipeDetector.getAction().LR)
                  {
                      Log.i("start value", "it might be started");
                      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                     Log.i("Swipe Action", getAction().toString());
                     Object listItem = listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                             InteractionsActivity.class);
                     startActivity(i);

                  } 
                  else if(!swipeDetector.swipeDetected())
                  {
                      Log.i("stop value", "it was stoped");
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                  }
          }
      });
```

But when comment the line `mSwipeDetected = Action.None;` in my SwipeDetector  `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:` statement, Activity opens properly, but when I return to the Activity, the background color of the listview item remains green and  `Log.i("stop value", "it was stoped");:` in my Activity `else if` statement can't be called. And when I uncomment it,   `Log.i("stop value", "it was stoped");` can be called, but the background color of listview item remains white and new Activity doesn't open. How should I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the activity, instead of doing `startActivity`, do it with `startActivityForResult`. That means you'll be able to detect when the other activity finishes and the user has come back to this one. Then you can set the color back to white.

Have a look here for how this works: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#usingintents_sub